# React - Is it inefficient to create multiple components via iteration?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning react, and I am creating a calendar as a challenge for myself, to create the cells of the calendar I fill an array with 42 "Square" components, is this inefficient? I am using date-fns if you are wondering about the date methods.

```
renderDays(){
    const dateFormat = "dddd";
    const currMonth = Array(42).fill(null);

    let startDate = lastDayOfMonth(subMonths(this.state.currentMonth, 1));
    startDate = subDays(startDate, this.dayOffset());

    for(let i=0;i<42;i++){
        currMonth.push(<Square offset={this.dayOffset()} date={format(addDays(startDate, i), "EEEE")} index={format(addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}/>)
    }

    return currMonth;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you need to render 42 squares, then iteration is the best way to do that, unless you want to explicitly type out 42 renders. Here are the React docs that show iteration being used for rendering multiple components: [Rendering Multiple Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)